# grunt-protractor-runner and Cross-Browser testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, protractor, end-to-end

I am able to successfully run test on chrome on my current set-up, however I am unable to add other browsers to my tests. I am using the grunt module 'grunt-protractor-runner' to run my e2e tests.

Having looked around I know the grunt-protractor-runner module does support multiCapabilities, so on the face of it I would expect the simple task of editing the target config file to include multiCapabilities and update chromeOnly to false.

Although I can pass multiCapabilities, I cannot however change the chromeOnly option to 'false' and get my tests to run successfully. My errors when passing Firefox and Chrome to multiCapabilities,

Running 2 instances of WebDriver[launcher] Runner Process Exited With Error Code: 8

```
------------------------------------
PID: 7812 (capability: chrome #1)
------------------------------------

Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

C:\Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-     webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1702
    throw error;
          ^
------------------------------------
PID: 6444 (capability: firefox #1)
------------------------------------

Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

C:\Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1702
  throw error;
        ^
```

I am running my set-up on Windows 7, using grunt-protractor-runner 1.0.1, protractor 0.23.1, chromedriver 2.9, and selenium-server-standalone 2.41.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that I've been able to resolve this problem - it related to not starting a standalone selenium server, which grunt-protractor-runner does not do on it's own.

The way around this is to either open a new console at the location of the protractor web-driver using `webdriver-manager start --standalone` and running the tests using grunt-protractor-runner as before; or as I am currently, using the grunt-protractor-webdriver module and including it within the grunt task to be called.

In my protractor.conf.js file I removed `chromeOnly: true` and added a multiCapabilities array of browsers.